# how does bower/npm know which github user a project sits within

Tags: node.js, github

When we all run `bower install angularjs` or `npm install ionic`, how do these tools (bower and npm) know which user the project sits in (e.g. ionic sits on [driftyco/ionic](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic)).

Additionally, if more than one project has the same name, which project takes precedence?

Comment: these tools do not "find" from github but from their own repos. npm ionic is here for instance : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic

Comment: People register projects into the bower and npm registries, and the package information at registration time determines where the code will be retrieved from. They're not "discovered" by bower or npm, and how they do it is explained quite well on their websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist different package repositories for each of the package managers that are available. Whenever you reference a package by name, the tool queries one of those repositories asking where to find the actual code that has to be downloaded for it to work.

For Bower, there's the [bower registry](http://bower.io/search/). For npm, there's the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/). And the like.

When you specify just a package name, the tool asks its registry for the data. If you specify the name and a GitHub repo, then it goes to that repo to get the code, and marks it as satisfying the `package-name` dependency.

The registry knows where to find the code because the package author registered all that info when publishing the package.

`npm` [defaults its registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry), but you can [scope your dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) to use a custom registry.

`gem`, the Ruby package manager, requires you to specify the registries you want to use - most of the time, just Rubygems.

But all of them know one way or another who to query to get the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Bower and NPM are agnostic when it comes to the packages the community submits. It is ultimately up to you, the developer, to confirm any NPM and Bower packages you incorporate into your software are the correct instances.

The best way to do that is to search and view the package at their respective Bower and NPM sites before installing.  There you can reference the GIT url and confirm its the correct package or not a fork before proceeding.